# How to color commands in kendo grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

Im new to mvc but i had 2 years experience with web forms applications in C#, I have a problem with coloring the commands in Kendo grid.

Usually in web forms, I use the `RowDataBound` function to check the value of the column, then use the `cssClass` to set the icon shape and color.

It will be something like this:

```
 LinkButton lbEdit = e.Row.Cells[7].FindControl("lbEdit") as LinkButton;

  if (lbEdit != null)
  {
    if (User != null)
        {
         lbEdit.Visible = true;
         lbEdit.CssClass = "fa fa-pencil-square-o  text-muted fa-2x";
         lbEdit.Enabled = false;
          }
          else
          {
           lbEdit.Visible = true;
           lbEdit.CssClass = "fa fa-pencil-square-o  text-success fa-2x";
            lbEdit.Enabled = true;
              }
      }
```

The previous code is just an example, but I'm struggling to do the same with Kendo grid in my new application, how can I do that?

Here is an example of the current Kendo grid:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Requested>()
      .Name("grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p => p.RequestNum).Width(200);
          columns.Bound(p => p.ProposedAppTitle).Width(200);
          columns.Bound(p => p.StatusId);
          columns.Bound(p => p.OriginatingDeptName);
          columns.Bound(p => p.AssignedPaUsername);
          columns.Bound(p => p.ProposedAppTitle);
          columns.Command(command =>
          {
              command.Custom("Edit").Text(" ").SendDataKeys(true).HtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Edit" }).IconClass("fa fa-pencil-square-o  text-success fa-lg").Click("Edit");


      })
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .PageSize(5)
          .Model(model =>
          {
              model.Id(p => p.Id);
          })
          .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Requested"))
      )
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable()
      .Filterable()

      )
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question directly, however, here is one way to add a custom button and respond to the click event, like a custom command.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.ItemID).Title("Configure").Sortable(false)
    .Width(275)
    .ClientTemplate(
        "<button  title='Edit the selected item' onclick='editItem(#=ItemID#)' tabindex='0' class='k-button k-button-icontext' id='btnEdit#=ItemID#' role='button' aria-disabled='false' type='button' data-role='button'><span class='k-icon k-i-pencil'></span>Edit</button>" +
        "#if(Active){#" +
            "<button title='Pause delivery of the selected item' onclick='pauseItem(#=ItemID#)' tabindex='0' class='k-button k-button-icontext' id='btnPause#=ItemID#' role='button' aria-disabled='false' type='button' data-role='button'><span class='k-icon k-i-exception'></span>Pause</button>" +
        "#}else{#" +
            "<button title='Resume delivery of the selected Item' onclick='resumeItem(#=ItemID#)' tabindex='0' class='k-button k-button-icontext' id='btnResume#=ItemID#' role='button' aria-disabled='false' type='button' data-role='button'><span class='k-icon k-i-refresh'></span>Resume</button>" +
        "#}#" +
        "<button title='Delete the selected item' onclick='deleteItem(#=ItemID#)' tabindex='0' class='k-button k-button-icontext' id='btnDelete#=ItemID#' role='button' aria-disabled='false' type='button' data-role='button'><span class='k-icon k-si-minus'></span>Delete</button>"
    )
    .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "Configure", style = "text-align:center" });
```

In the cshtml file and above where the grid is defined...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function editItem(itemID)
    {
      //do edit
    }

    function sendItem(itemID)
    {
        showWaitIndicator(true);
        var postDataOptions = {
            url: '@Url.Action("YourMethod", "YourConroller")',
            data: {
                ItemID:itemID
            },
            successFunction: function (data, status, xhr ) {
                showWaitIndicator(false);
            },
            errorFunction: function(){
                showWaitIndicator(false);
                alert("An error occurred while processing your request.");
            }
        };
        performYourAjaxPost(postDataOptions);
    }

    function deleteItem(itemID){
        //do delete
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this Kendo example, where classes are added to do the styling based on grid values: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Layout/style-rows-cells-based-on-data-item-values